# Updating UI while waiting for tasks to finish

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, task

I have a vb.net application processing a large amount of data. Due to the memory requirements of the process I am doing this batch-wise, with an overall planned structure as follows:

```
Do while Start < TotalNumberOfObjects

    [cache data used for the upcoming batch]

    For i = Start to Stop

        [process data using multiple tasks...for example:]
        t=taskfactory.startnew(doStuff(i))
        TaskList.TryAdd(t.ContinueWith(Sub()                                      
                                         Me.BeginInvoke(DelegateUpdateProgress, {progress})
                                       End Sub))
    Next

    [Wait for tasks to complete...
    Normally I would wait for the tasks using task.waitall(), 
    but this will cause the UI to wait to update until all tasks are complete]

    Start = Stop+1
    Stop = Stop+Increment

    [clear data from batch that was just completed]

loop
```

What's the proper way to:

1. Wait for all the tasks to complete before moving to the next batch?
2. Update the UI with the overall progress as each task completes?

My target framework is .NET 4.0.

I appreciate any input.

EDIT: Currently I am updating the UI upon completion of each task using `task.continuewith()` and calling `me.beginInvoke` to update the form,

```
TaskList.TryAdd(t.ContinueWith(Sub()                                      
                                 Me.BeginInvoke(DelegateUpdateProgress, {progress})
                               End Sub))
```

However, this is incompatible with how I would expect to wait for a list of tasks to complete, `task.waitall(tasklist)` because calling `task.waitall` will cause the UI thread to wait to update until all the tasks are complete.

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf Don't recomment `Application.DoEvents` (there are quite a few posts in SO explaining why it is a bad idea). This is the typical problem which has to be solved with multi-threading. If you want to keep it simple and are only interested in two threads (GUI + all the calculations), you might rely on the `BackgrounWorker`.

Comment: It's operating on several threads (GUI + Calculations + Database operations), hence I'm creating many tasks and waiting for them to complete.

Comment: Then I am not sure if I understand your problem. If you have various threads, the GUI is certainly updating (it doesn't get frozen). Are you asking about at what point should you display the new information to the user? At the end or in-between? Very difficult to tell with the information you are providing (= none); I guess that it is a matter of personal taste (and depends upon the exact situation you are talking about) Bear in mind that SO is about specific problems about specific programming issues (e.g., how can I avoid my GUI to get frozen?), not to discuss about abstract recommendations.

Comment: @varocarbas I updated the question to try and be more specific about the difficulty I am facing. I want to wait on a task, but can't because 'waiting' on a task means the UI thread will wait to update as well.

Comment: Sorry to say but your question makes still less sense now. If you make all the threads wait, they will certain wait. The question is: why are you making all the threads wait (at least, the GUI one) when you expect them to continue running? If you have a simple situation with GUI + lots of calculations (in many different methods and performing many different actions but all of them inter-dependent and thus requiring to wait one for the other), you might just use 2 threads. If the calculations are more complex and some of them have to run in parallel, you should define the waiting accordingly...

Comment: ... by making sure that the threads which should always be running never wait (the GUI or the ones not depending upon the outputs of others). Multithreading is not a nice-to-have feature in any context, it is a specific solution for a given problem (i.e., independent actions running concurrently). You can set some exceptions (i.e., one thread waiting), but converting your whole system into a big exception isn't too logical. The advice I give always to people who have reached a not-too-sensible point is: restart from the start by keeping it simple (= lowest number of threads required).

Answer (score 1):

Why don´t you put your routine in a Backgroundworker structure?

So, while you code process data, you´re ready to update any UI component you have.

If necessary, you may also update UI from Backgroundworker, but you need to have some special requirements to do this.

You may consult here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ywkkz4s1.aspx

Comment: Please don't link to external resources unless you also include the details from the linked page in your answer. Also, you've linked to a Portuguese language document.

Comment: Ops! My fault... Thanks for warning me. But curiously, the page appears here already in English, like I had set this before. Anyway, I will edit the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up a delegate and then use Dispatcher.Invoke

In the example below, a button is changed from enabled to disable (or the other way around):

```
   Delegate Sub SetRecordButtonEnabledCallback(ByVal Enabled As Boolean)
   Friend Sub SetRecordButtonEnabled(ByVal Enabled As Boolean)
        Me.btnDGRecord.IsEnabled = Enabled
   End Sub
```

after that all you need to do is call the following code from within your timer to invoke it:

> Dim DesiredValue as Boolean = True
>
> Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(New SetRecordButtonEnabledCallback(AddressOf SetRecordButtonEnabled), New
>   Object() {DesiredValue})